# Ancestor dragon. Inclusive or cumulative

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [Ancestor Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAncestor%20Dragon%5d) out and attack with 3 creatures does it trigger for creatures attacking and I gain 3 life or does it trigger for each attacking creature and I'd gain 3 life for each of the 3 attacking creatures thus gaining 9 life?

Answer (score 4):

[Ancestor Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAncestor%20Dragon%5d) says:

> Whenever one or more creatures you control attack, you gain 1 life for each attacking creature.

It triggers only once for each attack if you attack with one or more creatures. If you attack with 3 creatures you gain 3 life.

To clarify, the ability doesn't trigger for each attacking creature, just for each time you attack.

If you attack the second time (for example if you have an additional combat phase) then the ability will trigger again.

Comment: Note that "Whenever a creature you control attacks, you gain 1 life" would, in most situations ([Stifle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382377) is an exception), be functionality equivalent, and confusing in exactly the reverse way.

Comment: @Arthur I believe that with the Ancestor Dragon wording, there's only one lifegain event, while your wording isn't as clear.

Comment: @Accumulation Yes, the original wording makes it only one lifegain event, so [Ajani's Pridemate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205065) also cares about the difference. But I think they are equally clear. It is a [common enough wording](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[%22Whenever%20a%20creature%20you%20control%20attacks%22]+![Exalted]), although never attached to pure lifegain.

Comment: @Arthur [What, never](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=472982)?  (Notable for being in the same standard as Ajani's Pridemate and Heliod, the Sun-Crowned)

Comment: @ArcanistLupus You're right. I was too specific and the "white" made it not appear in my search.